# Programmatically adding map fragment to container adds it to the bottom

Tags: java, android, mapfragment

I have a contact application. A contact can have multiple addresses. When viewing a contact, a loop iterates through the database data and adds the address(es) to a container, as shown in the image. However, I don't understand why the fragments are added all the way to the bottom of the container, and not right under the respective `TextView` for that specific loop iteration.

Why can I not place the fragment underneath the TextView and how can I do that?

This is how I create the map fragment and add it to the container:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    MapFragment mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(onMapReadyCallback1());
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.dynamic_layout_holder, mapFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And this is the xml container:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dynamic_layout_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: can you post your xml file here

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman I've added the xml code for the container I use to inflate the various layouts in. Other than that, the rest of the xml should have no effect on this. (I inflate various views and TextViews inside this container, using for loops).

Comment: It is happening because map loads asynchronously and till then your loop reaches to next iteration

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman Okay I understand, so the solution would be not to load the map asynchronously (if that is possible).

Comment: It's actually because `FragmentTransaction`s are asynchronous by default, not anything to do with the map loading. You could use `FragmentManager#executePendingTransactions()` right after the `commit()`, or use the newer `commitNow()` method, if possible for your setup.

Comment: @MikeM ok, will look into that, thank you!